# GraphRequest returns only 25 results

Tags: android, facebook

```
new GraphRequest(
    accessToken1,"/me/invitable_friends",null,HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) 
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse());
                JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for(int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
                    System.out.println(jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).executeAsync();
```

The code above works fine.

but I'm getting only 25 results.

tried using limit but it is giving me error. returns error code : 400, see code below.

```
new GraphRequest(
    accessToken1,"/me/invitable_friends?limit=1000",null,HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback()
```

I want list of 50 users in one request.
and in another 50 in second request.

can I set offset with this request and how can I specify limit?

NOTE : I'm using latest facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a max amount for the limit, and setting a higher limit results in a much slower API call. A limit of 50 should be no problem though, just set it to 50 instead of 1000.

That being said, the best solution to get more than 25 entries is to use paging. How it works is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Comment: all i did is passed access token with the request. that returned me 50 users. 1000 was just example to explain.